# How save into database object of type A which refer to another object of type A?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mapping, self-join

In my webapp I have some categories. The category can be nested in another category. So my class structure is:

```js
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
@XmlRootElement
public class CategoryEntity implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 3738106090716428022L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = true)
@Null
private CategoryEntity parent;

 public CategoryEntity(String name) {
  super();
  this.name = name;
 }

 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public CategoryEntity() {
  super();
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public CategoryEntity getParent() {
  return parent;
 }

 public void setParent(CategoryEntity parent) {
  if (parent.equals(this))
   this.parent = null;
  else
   this.parent = parent;
 }
}
```

Solution above I found in web.

As you see, in database table I need refer to another object same type.
`My sql` table (I think it is correct in my case):

```
create table category (
    id bigint not null,
    name varchar(50),
    parent_id bigint null default null,

    constraint category_pk primary key (id),
    constraint fk_parent foreign key (parent_id) references category (id)
```

);

In this case I always get `NullPointerException`:

```js
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path [/Shop] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.tenebris.fx.service.rest.CategoryResource.createCategory(CategoryResource.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="parent_category_id")
```